# Hide button when label is not empty

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using WPF.

I want to show button when the label is not empty. When Label has a value, the button will be hidden.

How can I do this with WPF? Using `<Style>`?

Code:

```
<Label Name="lblCustomerName"/>
<Button Name="btnCustomer" Content="X" Visibility="Hidden" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a converter and bind it to the content of lblCustomer.

```
public class ContentNullToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

More on converters [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

Then in xaml you can do the following:

First line needs to be defined in your resources where you will need to qualify it with the namespace in which you created the class above. Once you have defined the resource you can use the second part.

```
<ContentNullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visConverter"/>

<Label Name="lblCustomerName"/>
<Button Name="btnCustomer" Content="X" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lblCustomer, Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource visConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblCustomerName.Text)) { 
    btnCustomer.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
} 
else {
    btnCustomer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```